# C++ : Similarities between Structure and Arrays?

Tags: c++

Are there any similarities between the structures and arrays in C++ ?

I was wondering to see this kind of question as both are different as one is user defined data type and other is derived data type with contiguous memory location storage.

Comment: Is there any problem with the question ?

Comment: It's not very clear what kind of answer you are looking for. There are not really any similarities between structs and arrays. What sort of similarities were you hoping for. They are completely different things

Comment: They contain "things"?

Answer (score 4):

There are some things that structs and arrays have in common, but generally they are thought of as conceptually separate. One situation in which you might be able to use either of them is if you want to store a known number of variables that are all of the same type.

I would recommend using an array if the data you are storing is a series where each value has the same meaning in some different context, and a struct if each value has a different meaning.

E.g.

You want to store a series of maximum temperature values for a single week. The meaning of each value is the same, all are maximum temperatures, so you use an array:

```
std::array<int, 7> week_max_temperatures;
```

You want to store the maximum and minimum temperatures and total rainfall for a day. The type of each value is the same, `int`, but the meanings are different, so you use a struct to avoid confusing minimum temperature, maximum temprature, and rainfall:

```
struct DailyWeatherData
{
    int max_temperature_deg_c;
    int min_temperature_deg_c;
    int total_rainfall_mm;
};
```

Here is a list of their similarities and differences:

Structs:

- Data members can be a combination of different types, but the types and number of members are fixed at compile time.
- Can have static and instance methods.
- Are copyable using `operator=()` (unless prohibited through copy constructor deletion or including a non-copyable member).
- Are copied when passed as a function parameter (unless passed as a reference or pointer).
- Data is stored in the object. Where they are stored in memory depends on whether they are defined as local variables or allocated using `new`. If the latter then you are responsible for memory management.

C-style arrays:

- May contain any number of elements, all of which are of the same type. The type is set at compile time and the number of elements is set when the array is created at run time.
- Cannot have user-defined methods associated with them.
- Are copyable, but only through `std::copy` or `memcpy`, not `operator=()`.
- Decay to pointers when passed as a function parameter.
- Where data is stored in memory depends on whether the array is created as a local variable or allocated using `new[]`. If the latter then you are responsible for memory management. In either case, the array variable acts like a pointer to the actual data.

[std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

- May contain any number of elements, all of which are of the same type. The type and number of elements are set at compile time.
- Cannot have user-defined methods associated with them (ignoring subclassing).
- Are copyable using `operator=()`.
- Are copied when passed as a function parameter (unless passed as a reference or pointer).
- Data is stored in the object. They are not typically allocated using `new`, so memory management is not a concern.

[std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

- May contain any number of elements, all of which are of the same type. The type is set at compile time and the number of elements can change during run time.
- Cannot have user-defined methods associated with them (ignoring subclassing).
- Are copyable using `operator=()`.
- Are copied when passed as a function parameter (unless passed as a reference or pointer).
- Data is stored outside the object, and memory management is handled automatically.